# How to access a Django UpdateView with using a uuid as slug

Tags: django, updateview

I'm wondering on how I can access a UpdateView by using a uuid as slug. So my goal is an URL like

http://myapp.example.de/edit/7efdbb03-bdcf-4b8a-85dd-eb96ac9954fd

I have defined the the view like this:

```
class DeviceEventUploadView(UpdateView):

    model = Event
    slug_url_kwarg = 'uuid_slug'
    slug_field = 'unique_id'
```

and urls.py like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('edit/<uuid:uuid_slug>',
        DeviceEventUploadView.as_view(),
        name='event_update'),
]
```

Here I'm getting:

```
Using the URLconf defined in myproject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    admin/
    ^edit/<uuid:uuid_slug> [name='event_update']

The current path, edit/7efdbb03-bdcf-4b8a-85dd-eb96ac9954fd/, didn’t match any of these.
```

Where is my failure in thinking?

Comment: You forgot to close the `<uuid:uuid_slug>`. It needs a closing angle bracket `>`. Furthermore this is `path` syntax.

Comment: Good catch. I've changed this and still not working (updating my question)

Comment: @frian: based on the error message, you still use `url`, not `path: a path converts it to a regex internally, and that will be specified in the error message.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Hmmm. I think I've found that issue now. The ending / was still present in the URL while testing. Without it seems to work. Stay tuned ;)

Comment: @frian: ah yes, normally paths should end with a slash, there is a Django setting named `APPEND_SLASH` that if true will look for the url first, then append a slash if it does not end with a slash, and try to look for the URL again.

Comment: i think the title should say "slug" and not "slag" lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to close the `<uuid:uuid_slug>`. It needs a closing angle bracket `>`. Furthermore this is `path` syntax. You thus define this with:

```
path(
    'edit/<uuid:uuid_slug>/',
    DeviceEventUploadView.as_view(),
    name='event_update'
),
```